# How to override VBO form action

Tags: 7, views

I have a VBO form that is embedded in an EVA field on a user page.

The VBO uses a Rules component with a text parameter to allow the current user to enter a value to be used as a variable to perform the rule component action.

The action of the VBO form (for user 55) is /user/55/55 , this means that when you run the VBO action, the page that allows you to add the variable is still the user page, and this causes a horrible busy page, when all I want is a plain page with the text field.

In light of this, I have tried setting my own new action using

`hook_form_alter`

and

`$form['action'] = '/my/url';`

but this results in a page not found on /my/url

Is there another way that I can control the parameter entry page URL for VBO?

**More information:**

The view doesnt have a path as it is an EVA (Entity Views Attachment) which is a view embedded inside the manage display settings of the User page. The issue im having is that after you select some rows and execute the VBO action, there is a text area variable (in this case, a message area to be included in the email sent by VBO) which appears in the same area as the rows you just selected.

This causes a bit of chaos as the URL for the form #action (FAPI) is user/55/55. What i want to know is if I can use hook_form_alter to change form #action to a new page, something like /send-rsvp where the user can fill in the text area and click send.

Comment: Not sure if I correctly understand your question, but what is the path (within page settings) of your VBO view? Is it something like "user/%/something" (which I suspect). Assuming that there is another way to make the **uid** available to your VBO / Rules Component combination (IMO there is one), would it be an option for you to use some other path that does not start with "user/%" so that your "*...is still the user page...*" is no longer applicable? PS: just to be 100% sure of your terminology: what do you mean by "VBO form action"?

Comment: Hi Pierre, I will update the question with some more info.

Comment: ok; a little progress to better understand your question. Some more questions: (1) that "user/55/55" (for user "55") is confusing. How would that look like for user 123? (2) About the "eMail sent by VBO": is that via one of the standard VBO operations you can select, or is it rather your Rules Component which has a Rules Action like "send an eMail" (might help to better understand if you add an export of your Rules Component)?

Comment: For user 123, it would be /user/123/123 , this appears to be the default behaviour of VBO as it uses $_GET["q"] to find the current url to build the #action. The "email sent by VBO" is the consequence of a Rules Component which evaluates a few variables and sends the email.

Comment: I'm unsure as to why you're using EVA for this instead of a regular page.. And what do you mean by the page is busy? And what chaos does the url cause?

Comment: EVA is needed to render a view inside a field group  horizontal tab on the users profile page. When the form is submitted, the user goes from user/123 to user/123/123 and then after entering the variable and submission goes to user/123/123/123. This appears to be the default behaviour and is likely a incompatibility of EVA and VBO